# How to recover accidentally deleted files in Go Daddy Root folder ?

Tags: asp.net, hosting, godaddy-api

I was hosting a web app developed in ASP.net MVC to **Go Daddy** hosting server. Once I have uploaded the files to `/httpdocs`, I had to remove the files again from the host. Instead of deleting what is in the `/httpdocs` folder, **Accidentally I deleted** some files in the `Root Folder`. I created some folders similar to the deleted folders and uploaded my web app again. But now I cannot see the web app. I am getting an error saying;

```
500 - Internal server error.There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.
```

Can someone please tell me how to recover the deleted files again and host my web app. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://in.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Domains/Accidentally-deleted-files-from-root-directory-website-is-down/td-p/18479   check this

Comment: I would say this is more of a question to their customer support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find the need to restore a file or folder that has become corrupted or deleted, there is a built in history on Godaddy hosted websites. This is a quick way of restoring it.

Step 1: Log in to you Account Manager
Godaddy Account

Step 2: Open you Web Hosting
Go to the hosting control panel of the website that you are wanting to restore

Step 3: Click Manage Button
Next to the hosting account you want to use - Click Manage

Step 4: Tools
Under the Tools section look for File Manager - Click File Manager

Step 5: File Manager
In File Manager click the Gear icon to the upper right. Select history view. This will give you the history of your files. You can pick what date you want to go back to by choosing the date from the calendar in the upper portion file manager.